# how redirect to a login page specified in a web.config file inside folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, web-config, authorization

I use this web.config file inside a folder to block users. I want to redirect to the page specified here:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
<authentication>
<forms loginUrl="~\paginas\login\loginvendedor2.aspx"/>
</authentication>
<authorization >
<deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

but I get redirected to the page specified in the web.config file in the root of the site

Answer (score 0):

Web.config has a feature called configuration inheritance.  There is an excellent article [here](http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/how-to-disable-web-config-inheritance-for-child-applications-in-subfolders-in-asp-net.aspx).

You need to edit the web.config file in the **root** directory and add the attribute `inheritInChildApplications="false"` to any tags you don't want the web.config in the sub-folder to inherit.  It should work on the `forms` tag.  However I can't test this right now and you may need to block inheritance from the `authenication` tag instead.